# conditional format formula based on top 3 values of another column

Tags: excel, formulas

I have a totals column (S) with conditional formatting for the top 3 values.
What I want to do is also set a conditional format to match the first column (A) which contains the name for that row of data.
So whatever 3 totals are formatted in column S, the corresponding cell in column A will also be highlighted.

[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSWSQ.jpg)

Comment: `=$S2>=LARGE($S$2:$S$25,3)` With the Applies To: $A$2:$A$25  Change the 25 in both formula to the last row in your dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically as suggested by @Scott Craner (and for the sake of an answer!) but combines formatting for both columns into a single rule. Select Columns A and S, HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=$S1>=LARGE($S:$S,3)
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select choice of formatting <kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd>.

There is little to be gained by restricting the range to which the CF rule applies and "whole column" may ease subsequent expansion, if any.

An alternative, depending what rule is already in place, would be merely to extend that to Column A by incorporating that into the Applies to range in the Conditional Formatting Rules Manager, for example:

```
=$A:$A,$S:$S
```

rather than say `$S2:$S25`.

[image]